How to automatically add a description field on the element in android development?
How to automatically add a description field on the element in android development?
My initial feeling is add something at the xml -> R compile stage。
or in the jetpack, we may could register some compiler extensions to add the description at the compile stage.
Could anyone here provide some examples or related links?

Which description field are you talking about?

I'm not sure what description field you are referring to. Some description values that you can set are through semantics:
   modifier = Modifier.semantics {
        contentDescription = "Check out"
        stateDescription = "what these do"
        paneTitle = "in the official documentation"
       }

Also, you can set a tag for testing purposes, like this:
Modifier.testTag("splash_screen_title")

